# Transfer ownership from unique_ptr<T,void(*)(T*)> to unique_ptr<const T,void(*)(const T*)>

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

With `reinterpret_cast` that would be something like:

```
std::unique_ptr< const T , void (*) (const T *) >
to_const ( std::unique_ptr< T , void (*) (T *) > &ptr ) 
{ 
  return { ptr.release() , 
           reinterpret_cast< void (*) (const T *) >( ptr.get_deleter() ) } ; 
}
```

Here casted deleter function will be called with object, which is actually, non-const.
But is there any cleaner way to do such transfer while avoiding UB?

Comment: Can you please format your code more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with `void (*)(const T *)` as the deleter type, no. But we can make our own deleter:

```
template <class T>
struct ConstDeleter {
    void (*deleter)(T*);

    void operator()(T const* ptr) {
        deleter(const_cast<T*>(ptr));
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<T const, ConstDeleter<T>>
to_const(std::unique_ptr<T, void (*)(T*)>& ptr)
{ 
  return {ptr.release(), ConstDeleter<T>{ptr.get_deleter()}};
}
```

This can be generalized to any deleter type.

Comment: in the name of const_cast i rewrote a most horrible part of my quite sophisticated (horrible) cascade for object allocation and construction.
for now i cant think of cleaner approach, thank you.